# Best practice for changes in Woocommerce core functions

Tags: woocommerce

There's a `woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button()` function in `woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php` that I'd like to change slightly. Specifically this function output several DOM elements and I need to insert one custom element in between those elements. Obviously I won't make the change in that file otherwise my change will disappear upon next update.

Is there a widely accepted way to override such core PHP function in WooCommerce?

Comment: Check if there's a hook or filter for the function that you can add to your functions.php file, so you can alter it without losing your change in future updates. See this link: https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Comment: That function is pluggable, so you can define it differently in your theme. Or since its only job is to call the `single-product/add-to-cart/variation-add-to-cart-button.php` template, you can override that template in your theme. See the documentation: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/